# TFSSecurity to change git branch permissions

Tags: visual-studio-2015, powershell-3.0, tfs-2015

I am implementing the TFS Security commands to change a git master branch acess control permissions to DENY for contribute field.

Below is the command I am using:

```
/tfssecurity.exe /a+ GitRepositories repositories/[543473b8-6186-42b3-bdab-b22bc44cc8f8/] GenericContribute n:'"[Projectname]\TFSGroup'" DENY /collection:CollectionURL"
```

I am using powershell 3.0 for this project and I get below error

> Error: The security namespace GitRepositories does not exist.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You missed a blank space in "Git Repositories" name space. Try following:

```
tfssecurity.exe /a+ "Git Repositories"
```

Comment: What would be the command to change the permissions only for Master branch on TFS?? I have the below command:    .\tfssecurity.exe /a+ "Git Repositories" repositories/[teamProject] GenericContribute n:'"[teamProject]\Contributors'" ALLOW /collection:CollectionURL/

Comment: @Akhi I cannot find any document about this either and would recommend you to set the security for branch from web portal.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error info, you are implementing with a not exist namespace.

You can use `tfssecurity /a` command to view a list of namespaces at the server level

> The namespace that contains the group from which you want to remove
>   the user or group. You can also use the tfssecurity /a command to view
>   a list of namespaces at the server level, the collection level, and
>   the project level.

More detail info of this command, please refer the link from MSDN: [Change groups and permissions with TFSSecurity](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd)