# How to deny contributions using TFSSecurity with Git

Tags: git, tfs

Using TFSSecurity I need to prevent contributions to certain Git branches. Previously we'd do this via the web interface to TFS and deny the contribute permission to the contributors group but now need to automate it.

I know I can turn make amendments to the master branch of repo using TFSSecurity but can't find an example of how to do it on another branch.

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

TFSsecurity command is using below  format to set permission:

```
tfssecurity /a+ Namespace Token Action Identity (ALLOW | DENY) [/collection:CollectionURL] [/server:ServerURL]
```

There is a concept of namespace

> **Namespace**
>
> The namespace that contains the group to which you want to add
>   permissions for a user or group. You can also use the `tfssecurity /a`
>   command to view a list of namespaces at the server, collection, and
>   project level.
>
> Source Link: [Change groups and permissions with TFSSecurity](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd#git-repository)

Only a namespace for git repo called `"Git Repositories"`, have not any namespace for specifically git branch.

For [setting git branch permissions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/branch-permissions), you may have to do this through web portal for now. Also take a look at this related question: [TFSSecurity to change git branch permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491082/tfssecurity-to-change-git-branch-permissions)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, its altering permissions at the child branch level that is proving elusive and the example you link to makes a change to the repo and by default the master branch. We're using tfs 2013 and I've looked at tf, tfssecurity and even the tfs api via c# nothing quite seems to fit, as you point out the web portal is the only place where currently I can do this and doesn't lend itself to automation.