# How to connect to TfsGit from vsts build task

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a ci build that should push changes to the git repo. I am using a PowerShell script to execute git commands. However, it fails with:

```
You need the Git 'GenericContribute' permission to perform this action.
```

I have already enabled

> Allow scripts to access OAuth token

However, that did not help. I am looking for a way to pass the Personal access token into the Powershell to be able to push to git. Below the error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you've got back there indicates that the token has made it through to your script and onto the request operation you're performing, but the identity associated with the token is not authorised to push to the destination repository.

You'll need to either change the identity associated with the OAuth token, or grant the "Contribute" permission to that identity (or one of the groups in which it is a member) for the git repository you are trying to operate against.

[image: Adding 'contribute' permission to the CI build account]

Comment: It was indeed a permissions issue

Comment: [Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491082/tfssecurity-to-change-git-branch-permissions) that sets the permission using the command line